# JS hide/unhide element based on dropdown list

Tags: javascript, stimulusjs

I'm a backend guy so forgive me my question. In my Rails 7 app I’ve got form with a checkbox. When the checkbox is checked two forms show up - `Exempt` (dropdown list) and `Tax Id`. I want to change that and as a user I want to see when a value is needed in the field Tax Id because of what I choose in Exempt with below requirements:

```
Exempt default is `none`
- it is not possible to enter something in the Tax Id field

Exempt value is set to `Reverse` or `Exempt`
- it is possible and mandatory to enter something in the Tax Id field
```

I'm using slim view components:

`form_component.slim`:

```
  .mt-3
    = render Forms::CheckboxComponent.new(name: "toggle-customer-tax-settings", label: t('.toggle_tax_settings'),
                                          checked: customer.tax_settings?, value: customer.tax_settings?)
    #customer-tax-settings-wrap style="#{'display: none;' unless customer.tax_settings?}"
      = form.fields_for :tax_settings, customer.tax_settings do |form|
        = render Customers::Form::TaxSettingsComponent.new(form:, disabled: !customer.tax_settings?, customer:)
```

`tax_settings_component.slim`:

```
= render Customers::Form::ExemptSelectComponent.new(form:, field: :exempt, include_blank: true, required: true, disabled:)
#customer_tax_settings_tax_id_wrap style="#{'display: none;' unless customer.tax_settings&.exempt.in?(%w[Reverse Exempt])}"
  = form.fields_for :tax_settings, customer.tax_settings do |form|
    = render Forms::TextFieldComponent.new(form:, field: :tax_id, required: true, disabled: !customer.tax_settings&.exempt.in?(%w[REVERSE EXEMPT]), label: t('.tax_id'))
```

With corresponding `form_controller.js`:

```
import { Controller } from 'stimulus';

function enableElements(elements, value) {
  elements.forEach((el) => {
    el.disabled = !value;
  });
}

function addToggleListener(toggleEl, wrapperEl) {
  if (!toggleEl) return;

  const fieldEls = wrapperEl.querySelectorAll('input, select');

  toggleEl.addEventListener('change', () => {
    if (toggleEl.checked === true) {
      enableElements(fieldEls, true);
      wrapperEl.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      wrapperEl.style.display = 'none';
      enableElements(fieldEls, false);
    }
  });
}

function toggleTaxId(event) {
  const exemptSelect = event.target;
  const taxIdInput = document.querySelector("#customer_tax_settings_tax_id");
  const shouldShowTaxId = exemptSelect.value === "REVERSE" || exemptSelect.value === "EXEMPT";
  taxIdInput.disabled = !shouldShowTaxId;
  taxIdInput.required = shouldShowTaxId;
}

export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    const exemptSelect = this.element.querySelector("#customer_tax_settings_exempt");
    addToggleListener(
      this.element.querySelector("input[name=toggle-customer-tax-settings]"),
      this.element.querySelector("#customer-tax-settings-wrap")
    );
    if (exemptSelect) {
      exemptSelect.addEventListener("change", toggleTaxId);
      toggleTaxId({ target: exemptSelect });
    }
  }
}
```

So now the feature works partially - it hides/show only the `Exempt` dropdown depending if the checkbox is checked (as expected) but not showing the `Tax Id` field when chose e.g Reverse from the dropdown list (here is the inspected list element `<option value="REVERSE">Reverse</option>`). No errors in the console tab inside the chrome.

How to change that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this library but my guess is `connect()` only runs once at the start and so `exemptSelect.addEventListener` is never called as it's blocked by the if guard, which won't reevaluate.

That would mean that nothing happens when changing the value, which is what you are seeing.

You should add this event listener even if the dropdown is not always visible. There is no harm in doing so.

```
export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    const exemptSelect = this.element.querySelector("#customer_tax_settings_exempt");
    addToggleListener(
      this.element.querySelector("input[name=toggle-customer-tax-settings]"),
      this.element.querySelector("#customer-tax-settings-wrap")
    );
    exemptSelect.addEventListener("change", toggleTaxId);
  }
}
```

I think though you are also not using the lib properly as it appears it has its own semantics for events: https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/actions.